# Not able to create mask on text in image

Tags: python, opencv

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Load image, grayscale, Gaussian blur, Otsu's threshold
image = cv2.imread('1.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (7,7), 0)
thresh = cv2.threshold(blur, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# Create rectangular structuring element and dilate
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (5,5))
dilate = cv2.dilate(thresh, kernel, iterations=4)


cv2.imshow('dilate', dilate)

cv2.waitKey()
```

I am trying to mask text in image using this code. But it is working for only one image.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: `cv2` doesn't mask text but only some colors. it doesn't know that you want mask text. It would need OCR or something more complext to detect text before masing